# Use percentage to trigger an occurrence in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am  working on a game and, I would like to trigger an occurrence based on a percentage. So, according to my Hero's action the chance of the occurrence goes up or down. The question is, lets say because of how you play the variable "ChanceOFSpawningKremlin" is 75%, I am unsure how to use that 75% in a function to cause the occurrence, I was thinking of selecting a random number and if that number is between 0 and 75 then cause the occurrence, however for some reason I don't think that's the best way.

```
float random = Random.value;

 if (random<chanceOfSpawningKremlin)//75%
 {
    spawnBeast();
}
```

As a result, any assistance to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classical way to do this is choosing a value between 0 and 1 exclusive uniformly at random, and then checking whether that value is strictly lower than your chance. So in your case:

```
var random = new Random(seed);
var chanceOfSpawningKremlin = 0.75;

if(random.NextDouble() < chanceOfSpawningKremlin)
{
    SpawnBeast();
}
```

EDIT:

I forgot Unity has its own `Random` class. And that class is pretty wonky, since it returns values in `0.0` to `1.0` INCLUSIVE on both ends. As long as your probability is not equal to `1.0`, however, you can ignore that and use it like this:

```
var chanceOfSpawningKremlin = 0.75f;

if(Random.Value() < chanceOfSpawningKremlin)
{
    SpawnBeast();
}
```

If your probability was ever `1.0` you need to make a special case out of it and treat is as always succeeding.

Please note that in both cases you are using probabilities as values between `0.0` and `1.0`, not percentages. If you want to keep your values as percentages then divide them by `100.0` when using in probability testing.

Comment: Using a constant seed would lead to the same spawn behaviour every game, while still varying in spawn intervals. +1

If total randomness is wanted, use random seed.

Comment: @KYL3R You're saying Random.Value() is not random enough?

Comment: @Niana **a random seed** is necessary if you want the game to be different than the last time. `DateTime.Now.Ticks` is often used as the seed

Comment: Please note that a seed initialization should be done once during game start. Use `Random.InitState(seed)` for that.

Comment: @Bijan im a little confused, So I should say `var random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Ticks);` ?

Comment: @Niana you should probably keep using the Unity's `Random` library (my first snippet was for the .NET Framework class) in which case you would do
`Random.InitState(DateTime.Now.Ticks);` at game start.

Comment: @Niana just like V0ldek said in the comment above. And keep in mind it's always better to use unity classes and avoid .netframework classes where ever possible.